# Underscore template not getting values?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

So, I am having difficulties getting my object's data into my underscore template.

**JS**

```
var details = SD.defaultView.extend({
    el: 'page',
    template: JST['app/www/js/templates/sex.ejs'],
    information: {
        header: 'some information!!!',
        image: '/img/path.jpg'
    },
    render: function () {
        var infom = _.template(this.template(), this.information);
        c(_.template(this.template()).source);
        this.$el.html(infom);
    }
});
```

**JST Template**

```
<% console.info(this.information); %>
<sexform></sexform>
```

**Console Output**

```
Object { header="some infromatoin!!!", image="/img/path.jpg"} global.js (line 34)
Object { header="some infromatoin!!!", image="/img/path.jpg"} global.js (line 34)

//output of c(_.template(this.template()).source);
function(obj){
var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join,print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');};
with(obj||{}){
__p+='<sexform></sexform>';
}
return __p;
}
```

Now, as you can see the object is getting passed via `this` but intresting if i try this:

```
 <% c(this.information.header); %>
 <sexform></sexform>
```

with the following error:

```
TypeError: this.information is undefined  templates.js (line 21)
...__e = _.escape, __j = Array.prototype.join;function print() { __p += __j.call(ar...
```

This, should 100% work with the dot notation.

Comment: please test what exactly `this.template()` returns?

Comment: One step ahead of you :) exactly what you'd expect sadly: `<% console.info(arguments);  %><sexform></sexform>` code no longer returns the data error, rather embarrassing I forgot to run grunt dev, which obviously updates my code. so now its `var infom = _.template(this.template(), this.data);`

Comment: So code is working or not?!

Comment: heh, certainly not working :) The `console.info` is still the same.

Comment: arguments must be [Object, function], This code is running somewhere that is not underscore.js, please output comment result of `_.template(this.template()).source`.

Comment: I feel i should start again to avoid confustion. In fact i'll update my quesiton. Give me a secon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39378/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-kit-o)

Answer (score 4):

That's because data is undefined! you are passing `this.data` not `{data: this.data}`, therefore argument of template is `{header: '..', image: '..'}`

correct code is :

```
var wank = SD.defaultView.extend({
    el: 'page',
    template: JST['app/www/js/templates/sex.ejs'],
    data: {
        header: 'interesting!!!',
        image: '/img/path.jpg'
    },
    render: function () {
        // this line is changed
        var infom = _.template(this.template(), {data: this.data});
        this.$el.html(infom);
    }
});
```

**Edit**

`template: JST['app/www/js/templates/sex.ejs']` is compiled template, so :

```
var infom = _.template(this.template(), {data: this.data});
```

is wrong and it must be

```
var infom = _.template({data: this.data});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, `this.data` is defined. The data issue is coming from template.js, i've updated the question to show the console.info in more detail. Sorry about that